# How to add and highlight rows on input of particular column in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

In the attached google sheet.

**Google Sheet -** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KxqaI-GYWur0Knt_bShI0GURucqU_cawu_sCoG_8Xlc/edit?usp=sharing

I need to execute the following two operations on input.

1. Add same number of rows against which `ID` if any user put the value as 1 in column K.

For Example, If I input 1 in column K for `ID` = `ID_3` which has 5 rows, I want to append that five rows below where the last instance of `ID_3` and in appended rows all the values should be the same as `ID_3` except column C which will now be `ID_3_Append`, column K and O which should be blank for appended rows.

2. If someone input value as 1 in column M, We need to check for which `ID` it belongs and look for that id in column E, F, and G and highlight rows with red color if `ID` against which user has provided input as 1 is available in column E, F, and G.
3. If someone adds value as 1 in change type, I need to update the column B to I in the `Test_1` sheet from `Put_list` but want to keep the `Mark Status` for common ID (if it has any `Mark Status) between earlier` Test_1`and`Put_list` unchanged. Also, we need to highlight the dependent rows accordingly.

Once we update column B to I we need to change the Name from 'Call' to 'Put'.

Comment: I can't think of any way of achieving the row insertions without using a script, which others are better positioned to provide.  But for clarification, are the cells in column K always going to be merged, for adjacent rows with the same ID?  It may, however, have no impact on a solution.

Comment: @kirkg13 : We can keep it as un-merged, but if anyone enter value as 1 against the same ID in column K we should automatically copy that value for all the blank cell in column K for that particular ID.

Comment: @kirkg13 - Is this problem achievable by Googlesheet?, I need your opinion.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is.  I know it could be done with scripts, similar to VBA code in Excel.  It might be possible to do it without scripts, but it would probably be messy and require multiple sheets.  I'm sure someone here will be able to help you, if you give it a couple of days.  Especially with the bounty you've offered...

Comment: added some notes in my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY({Test_1!A:O; 
 IFERROR(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Test_1!C2:C, SORT({Test_1!C2:C, Test_1!K2:K}, 2, 0), 2, 0))=1, 
 {Test_1!A2:A, Test_1!B2:B, Test_1!C2:C&"_Append", Test_1!D2:J, Test_1!X2:X*0, 
  Test_1!L2:L, Test_1!X2:Y*0, Test_1!O2:O}, 
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""}), 
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""})}, 
 "where Col1 is not null and not Col3 matches '"&
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "×", UNIQUE(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Test_1!C2:C, 
 SORT({Test_1!C2:C, Test_1!N2:N}, 2, 0), 2, 0))=1, Test_1!C2:C, )))&"' order by Col3", 1);
  
 IF(LEN(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 UNIQUE(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Test_1!C2:C, SORT({Test_1!C2:C, Test_1!N2:N}, 2, 0), 2, 0))=1, Test_1!C2:C, ))))>0, 
 QUERY({IF(Put_list!A2:A="",,IFERROR(Put_list!A2:A*1, "Put")), Put_list!A2:H, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(Put_list!B2:B&"♦"&COUNTIFS(Put_list!B2:B, Put_list!B2:B, ROW(Put_list!B2:B), "<="&ROW(Put_list!B2:B)), 
 {Test_1!C2:C&"♦"&COUNTIFS(Test_1!C2:C, Test_1!C2:C, ROW(Test_1!C2:C), "<="&ROW(Test_1!C2:C)), Test_1!J2:O}, {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0))}, 
 "where Col3 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 UNIQUE(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Test_1!C2:C, SORT({Test_1!C2:C, Test_1!N2:N}, 2, 0), 2, 0))=1, Test_1!C2:C, )), 
 UNIQUE(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Test_1!C2:C, SORT({Test_1!C2:C, Test_1!N2:N}, 2, 0), 2, 0))=1, Test_1!C2:C&".+", )))&"'"), 
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""})}, "where Col1 is not null order by Col3", 1))
```

[image]

---

[image]

```
transcript:

we start with array of {C, K} columns that we sort based on K column so if K column contains 1 then it will be moved up                                                 
this is convinient for VLOOKUP coz it will always look for 1st unique value eg. exactly wat we need if our array is sorted                                                  
so we vlookup C values to match our sorted array and return column K for all same IDs                   2 stands for 2nd column from sorted array and 0 stands for "exact match"                                
if no match is found vlookup will output #N/A error so we wrap it into IFNA - then if no match is found vlookup will output empty rows                                                  
then we put this into IF statement... if our vlookup outputs 1, we output our columns (again in {array} form                                                    
if our vlookup outputs 0 then we output array of 15 empty cells in a row {"","","", .....}                  this is because we use arrays {} and all ranges in arrays needs to be of same size                              
                    our table has 15 columns so if some error would happen the we would get error in one single cell aganist our 15 columns                                 
                    this way we avoid "array_literal error" having {15 columns; 15 cells in a row which is also 15 columns}                             
                    ; semicolon puts these two arrays/ranges under each other while , comma will put then next to each other                                
so if vlookup results in 1 then we assemble our array with ranges... A, B columns are same then we append to C column the phrase "_Append" with &                                                   
D:J columns are same... then we force column of zeros by multipling random empty column (X) with 0                      etc.                            
then again we use {"","","", ....} within IFERROR to deal with any possible error at this point                                                 
next we put all written above under our whole range Test_1!A:O and we wrap it into QUERY where we state to filter out all empty rows where Col1 is empty and 2nd condition of our query states                                                  
that Col3 of our array cant match our regex pattern which we assemble with TEXTJOIN formula                                                 
    | stands for "or" in regex. 1 in textjoin means "all non empty cells". then we use × (unique symbol) in case textjoin would output empty cell on its own resulting in some error somewhere                                              
    again we perform same vlookup, same ifna and same IF but now we output only C column and we are interested only into UNIQUE values                                              
then within the query we sort / order by Col3 our table and 1 at the end stands for "header rows"
```

Comment: Why not just copy paste the explanation text here?

Comment: Just WOW...  But kind of what I was expecting, from one of the experts...

Answer (score 3):

This may answer the second part of your question.
Select the range of rows you want the red conditional formatting on, for example A2:A12 in your sample sheet.
Select Format - Conditional Formatting, verify the range, and apply a custom formula, as follows:

```
=OR(
  IF($E2<>"NA",IFERROR(MATCH($E2,FILTER($C$1:$C$12,$M$1:$M$12=1),0)),0),
  IF($F2<>"NA",IFERROR(MATCH($F2,FILTER($C$1:$C$12,$M$1:$M$12=1),0)),0),
  IF($G2<>"NA",IFERROR(MATCH($G2,FILTER($C$1:$C$12,$M$1:$M$12=1),0)),0))
```

[image]
The `FILTER` pulls which IDs have a "1" in the update column, ColM.

`MATCH` looks to see if the ID in the Dependency column is in that filtered list.

The `IFERROR` sets the result to zero if no match.

And the initial `IF`, filters out the NA values in the Dependency column.

This logic is replicated for each Dependency column, so three IFs.

And the whole thing is wrapped in an OR function, so if any of the Dependency columns have a matching ID, the whole row is flagged for red.

I've applied this in a tab added to your sheet, Test_1-GK.

Let me know if this helps.

I'm afraid I didn't understand the first part of your question.  I got confused with this bit:

*I want to append that five rows below where the last instance of ID_3 and in appended rows all the values should be same as ID_3 except column C which will be now be ID_3_Append, column K and O which should be blank for appended rows.*

Comment: Thanks, the second part is working fine. In the first part I just want that if someone enter 1 in add duplicate I want to append all the rows associated to that particular `ID` in the same order exactly below where that ID against which 1 entered. Also, I want to rename the `ID` of appended rows from `Actual_ID` to `Actual_ID_Append` in my example it is `ID_3_Append`